# Stringify object with array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ajax, database

I have some inputs. User fills them and clicks send button. I want the data to store in database (couchDB).

The problem: I can save in database one object(div with multiple inputs).
[image: database]

But when the user creates another div with inputs and tries to send 2 of them or even more - I get an error
[image: node cmd]

what I have so far:

this is the structure I am trying to send:

[image: structure]

and this is a code:

App:

```
 handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let myRequest = new Request(
        'http://localhost:80/send',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(
                this.state.divs // <- here is an array of objects. Won't work. 
                                // But if I send only the first one  `this.state.divs[0]`  it will do 
                                // the job and data will be stored in database as on the first picture.
            )
        }
    );
     fetch(myRequest)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
   };
```

Server:

```
server.post('/send', (req, res) => {
questionsDB.insert(
    req.body
).then(
    (antwort) => {
        console.log(antwort);
        res.send(JSON.stringify({
            status: 'ok'
        }))
    }
  );
});
```

What I am doing wrong? Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thought is you cannot insert an array of objects using the insert function. You have to loop through each object or use a method for bulk inserts.

Comment: Right! bulk() method! Oh my....   Thank you! You saved me )